# Reduce APK size in Xamarin.Forms, APK size 80MB

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Cannot reduce xamarin apk size below 80 MB, did the following:

- enabled proguard
- Configuration: Release
- Platform: Active (Any CPU).
- Enable Multi-Dex: true
- Enable developer instrumentation (debugging and profiling): false
- Linking: SDK and User Assemblies(Tried sdk assemblies only also)
- Supported architectures: Selected all

Visual studio community 2017 version: 15.9.6
Need some help on this...

Comment: selecting All Architectures is going to create a bigger APK

Comment: @Jason now enabled only armeabi-v7a ..still not reduced

Comment: @SushiHangover tried to unzip apk in cmd `unzip xxx.apk -d xxx` not working

Comment: @SushiHangover no option to extract..add to archive only

Comment: @SushiHangover winzip..can i reduce these files from root folder?

Comment: @VipinKrishna ? reduce? I am asking for you to UNZIP the apk in order to determine what is the break down of the various folders are in order to determine what is causing the 80mb size.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using any unwanted Nugets? they can be pesky and painful when it comes to the size of your build.

Comment: You have "tried" plenty of things to reduce your APK size, but before doing this, it might be worth understanding the cause of the APK bloat first. Follow what @SushiHangover is suggesting and use a tool like https://windirstat.net/ to get an idea of what is taking so much space in your APK.

Comment: This question cannot be answered as @JonDouglas said. You cannot reduce the size without knowing what is causing it and you haven't provided any details that could help. The question should be closed, IMHO.

Comment: @G.hakim unwanted nugets there; livexaml,gorilla,modernhttpclient,xlabs etc..uninstalled..now apk reduced to 21 !!!

Comment: Shall I post it as an answer?

Comment: @G.hakim yes surely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the unwanted assemblies and image resources and it should solve your problem, they can be pesky and painful when it comes to the size of your build.

Also only select the Abi's that are needed for your release build as per me `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64-v8a` should be enough.

Also in case, this does not help as [SushiHangover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4984832/sushihangover) suggested unzip the Apk and check what is causing the issue also check the [windirstat](https://windirstat.net/) just like [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048571/jon-douglas) suggested.

Revert in case of queries.
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Solution number one would be to use Link user assemblies and SDK. If you totally fail linking your user assemblies then i invite you to do the following:

In project options check 'Generate one package (.apk) per selected ABI'. That will create smaller apks for each processor platform.

Now it is possible that you still fail to publish anything because VS will try to upload the 80mb common apk along with smaller apks for dedicated platforms, resulting in "apk too big" error.

So after you sign apks for publishing open the distribution folder, then the 'signed-apks' subfolder. Inside you will see apks built for different platforms, the picture will be similar to this:

[image]

Now open Google developper console and create a release, then upload manually apks one by one except the huge one. You are then good to go.

I guess we are limited to this option until we get a new compiler/linker with VS 2019 or maybe earlier.

Comment: unwanted nugets there; livexaml,gorilla,modernhttpclient,xlabs,aiforms etc. were uninstalled..now apk reduced to 21 !!!

Comment: For me such size for due to using AOT, unavoidable size increase atm. Looks like xamarin team does much atm to reduce startup time, even to aot the app startup part, so would hopefully change in the future.

Comment: @NickKovalsky To many acronyms for a newbie questioner don't you think :P